# Observing the limiting behavior of the ODE $z' = z(z-a)(1-z)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence

Consider the ODE given by

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
z'(t) &= z(t) \cdot (z(t) - a) \cdot (1-z(t)) && t>0\\
z(0) &= z_0
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

where $z_0 \in (0,a)$ and $a \in (0,1)$.

I would like to show that

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} z(t) = 0$$

in this scenario - preferably whilst avoid solving the ODE explicitly (since I have reason to believe it should be an "obvious" result).

---

As context, this comes up in solving the nonlinear PDE

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&u_t - \Delta u = u(u-a)(1-u) &&(x,t) \in \Omega \times (0,\infty) \\
&\partial_n u \equiv 0 &&(x,t) \in \partial \Omega \times (0,\infty) \\
&u(x,0) = \varphi(x) &&x \in \Omega
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

wherein:

- $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$
- $\varphi(x) \ge 0$
- $\varphi\not \equiv 0$
- $\| \varphi\|_\infty < a$

which is Example $3.4$ in Mingxin Wang's *Nonlinear Second Order Parabolic Equations* (ISBN-10: 0367711982).

It is claimed without proof that

$$ z_0 < a  \implies z(t;z_0) \xrightarrow[\text{uniformly}]{t \to +\infty} 0$$

and

$$
z_0 > a  \implies z(t;z_0) \xrightarrow[\text{uniformly}]{t \to +\infty} 1
$$

but I cannot for the life of me see why.

---

Clearly, $z_0 < a$ gives $z'(t) < 0$ at $t=0$, and similarly $z_0 > a$ gives $z'(t) > 0$ there. However, I'm not sure what to do with this information; what does it imply, if anything, about the future times? Ideally we'd be able to bound $z$ above/below as needed and use some sort of monotone convergence theorem to establish the desired result.

If we do calculate an explicit solution to the ODE ([Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%27%28t%29+%3D+z%28t%29+*+%281+-+z%28t%29%29+*+%28z%28t%29+-+a%29)), then we get a result that is implicit and uses logarithms: without accounting for $z_0$, we'd have

$$C + t = \frac{1}{a(a-1)} \Big( a \ln(1 - z(t)) - (a-1) \ln(z(t)) - \ln(z(t) - a) \Big)$$

and if we desire this to be well-defined over the reals, then we see that

$$0 < a < z(t) < 1$$

in the scenario I wish to focus on (where $z_0 < a$). This at least gives upper and lower bounds on $z$, but it's not clear if those are the tightest (or if, indeed, some amount of information is lost in solving the ODE).

---

Does anyone have any ideas? Hopefully I'm just overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a \in (0, 1).$

Suppose $z(t)$ solves the initial value problem,

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
z'(t) &= z(t)\,(z(t) - a)\,(1-z(t)) && t>0\\
z(0) &= z_0
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Define the open set $U = (-\infty, a)$ and the classic Lyapunov candidate $$\begin{aligned}V: U &\to \mathbb{R}\\ z &\mapsto z^2.\end{aligned}$$ Observe that,

$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{V}(z(t)) &= 2\,z(t)\,\dot{z}(t)\\
&= 2\,z(t)\,[ z(t)\,(z(t) - a)\,(1-z(t)) ], \\
&= 2\,V(z(t))\,(z(t) - a)\,(1-z(t)).\end{aligned}$$

If $z(t) \in U,$ then $z(t) - a < 0$ and $1 - z(t) > 0.$ As a result, their product $(z(t) - a)\,(1 - z(t)) < 0.$ Moreover, $V(z(t)) > 0$ for all $z(t) \in U \setminus \{0\}.$ Combine these data to find, $$\dot{V}(z(t)) < 0,$$ when $z(t) \neq 0.$ This establishes asymptotic stability of solutions initialized in $U$ by Lyapunov's Second Method.

In fact, this is the maximal stable region since $z = a$ is an invariant set that solutions can't cross over.